# Using the jQueryUI Datepicker to request a Rails view based on a specific date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a jQueryUI Datepicker on a user's profile page.  When the user selects a date, rather than populate a text box with the date value, I'd like to immediately send a `GET` request to obtain statistics for that user on the date picked.

The URL would be something like this:

`/users/1?date=20110905`

And then my `UsersController` would look at `params[date]` and query the model for the appropriate date-based data.

The part I'm having trouble with is the JavaScript part.  I'll need to hook into the jQueryUI Datepicker's `onSelect` event, but after I catch the event:

1. How do I get the user ID from within the JavaScript code?
2. How should I submit the `GET` request?  I want a full page reload, so should I use `window.location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the path of the URL with `location.pathname`, and you can reload the current page by assigning `location.href` to the URL you want to reload the page with. So, you would probably be looking at something like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        // location.pathname == '/users/1'
        var userId = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
        var dateText = ...

        location = location.href + "?date=" + dateText;;
    }
});
```

Note, `location.href` gives you the entire URL, including querystring (for GET method) and hash, while `location.pathname` only gives you the path of URL. See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location#Properties) for the `location` object.

Comment: Could I remove the `$.get` altogether and just do `window.location = window.location.href + "?date=" + dateText;`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Somehow I mistakenly read you want to do AJAX first. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When processing ERB file, <% %> tags are processed first, on server. Then, the result is sent to the browser. So, you can inject ERB tags into your javascript, like this:

```
var user_id = <%= user.id %>;
```

Then, you can use window.location to redirect, for example to index action:

```
window.location = "<%= url_for :action => :index %>";
```